# Laravel form data not saving in neo4j graph DB

Tags: php, forms, laravel, neo4j, csrf-protection

I wrote a `laravel form`, its screen shot is as given below:
[image: form]
And I use neo4j for storing that form data.
Here is the code:
**`app/views/duck-form.blade.php`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel Form Validation!</title>

    <!-- load bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body    { padding-bottom:40px; padding-top:40px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Register! </h1>
        </div>

        @if ($errors->has())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                {{ $error }}<br>        
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif

        <!-- FORM STARTS HERE -->
        <form method="POST" action="/ducks" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('name')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" value="{{ Input::old('name') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" value="{{ Input::old('email') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('email')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                @if ($errors->has('password')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password_confirm')) has-error @endif">
                <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password_confirm" class="form-control" name="password_confirm">
                @if ($errors->has('password_confirm')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password_confirm') }}</p> @endif
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. I added `'Artdarek\Neo4j\Neo4jServiceProvider'` to providers array in `app/config/app.php`.
 2. I added `neo4j` configuration in `app/config/database.php`

```
 'neo4j' => [
            'default' => [
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => 7474,
            'username' => null,
            'password' => null,
        ],
    ],
```

3. Then I added a controller for that form:

```
<?php

class DuckController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('duck');
    }

}
```

4. This is my `routes.php`.

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

// route to show the duck form
Route::get('ducks', function() 
{
    return View::make('duck-form');
});

// route to process the ducks form
Route::post('ducks', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{

    // create the validation rules ------------------------
    $rules = array(
        'name'             => 'required',                       // just a normal required validation
        'email'            => 'required|email|unique:ducks',    // required and must be unique in the ducks table
        'password'         => 'required',
        'password_confirm' => 'required|same:password'          // required and has to match the password field
    );

    // create custom validation messages ------------------
    $messages = array(
        'required' => 'The :attribute is really really really important.',
        'same'  => 'The :others must match.'
    );

    // do the validation ----------------------------------
    // validate against the inputs from our form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

    // check if the validator failed -----------------------
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // redirect our user back with error messages       
        $messages = $validator->messages();

        // also redirect them back with old inputs so they dont have to fill out the form again
        // but we wont redirect them with the password they entered

        return Redirect::to('ducks')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password', 'password_confirm'));

    } else {
        // validation successful ---------------------------

        // our duck has passed all tests!
        // let him enter the database

        // create the data for our duck
        $duck = new Duck;
        $duck->name     = Input::get('name');
        $duck->email    = Input::get('email');
        $duck->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        // save our duck
        $duck->save();

        // redirect ----------------------------------------
        // redirect our user back to the form so they can do it all over again
        return Redirect::to('ducks')
            ->with('messages', 'Hooray!');

    }

}));
```

5. This is my model file for `form`:

```
<?php

class Duck extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'email', 'password');

}
```

6. This is my model for `neo4j`:

```
<?php

    //use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

    class database extends Eloquent {

        public function index($name, $email, $password, $password_confirm) {

            $formData = Neo4j::makeNode();
            $formData->setProperty('name',$name)
                    ->setProperty('email',$email)
                    ->setProperty('password',$password)
                    ->setProprty('password_confirm',$password_confirm)
                    ->save();

        }

    }
```

When I click on that `submit` button in that form, I get this error:
[image: error]
[ **`Edit`** ]
I was working on it:
This is the new error which I got:
[image: error1]
Is it a `csrf` token issue?
It is pointing to:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

I'm unable to resolve it since 5 hours and data isn't getting stored in neo4j DB. How can I fix it?

Comment: It expects a hidden _token input in your html form, I can't find it. So yes it seems to be a csrf token issue.

Comment: Well.... How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but more with Symfony, so maybe the docs can help you http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `CSRF Protection Filter`, your form must be declared in your blade as such:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => URL::to("/ducks"))) }}
```

And closed:

```
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This will render the same form in your html as using:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::to("/ducks") }}">...</form>
```

But will also add the hidden `_token` element that you are missing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="value_of_token"/>
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

Or, if you don't want to recreate your `<form>`, you may simply use:

```
{{ Form::token() }}
```

Somewhere inside your existing `<form>` tag to create it.

Comment: Vote up my question if you want :)

Comment: Woops, thought I already did. It was actually a great question :P

Comment: One more thing: Form data must be pushed to neo4j DB. How can I do it? Can you check the question again? Thank you for upvoting :)

Comment: I'm not familiar was `neo4j` actually. But if it's just a database, define it the same as your `duck` model, and insert it using the same syntax: `$neo47 = new Neo4j; $neo4j->property = "something"; $neo4j->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, might be you need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```