# 'Undefined index: Driver' error while using neo4j as DB for laravel form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, neo4j

My Scenario: 
I've written a form by using laravel php framework. I want that form data to be saved into graph data base ( Neo4j DB ). Here is my `app/config/database.php`.

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'neo4j',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'appdb',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
        'neo4j' => array(
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => 7474,
            'username' => null,
            'password' => null,
        ),

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => array(

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ),

    ),
);
```

Problem faced: 
When I fill that form and press on Submit button, the data doesn't get pushed to neo4j DB. It displays an error: 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Undefined index: driver

Expected Result:
Form data needs to be saved in neo4j DB when clicked on submit button.

Comment: add a new element to `neo4j array` like, `'driver' => 'neo4j',`

Comment: I tried it and I got this error: `InvalidArgumentException, Unsupported driver [neo4j]`

Comment: Did you looked if laravel has a supported driver for neo4j ? No it doesn't. The error message is self explaining. If you want to learn how to use neo4j with php / laravel you can have a look at the neo4j documentation : http://neo4j.com/developer/php/

Comment: use #https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent

Comment: @K.Toress: I installed that `NeoEloquent`, updated the project, reran the local server and this is the error which I got: `InvalidArgumentException 
Database [neo4j] not configured.`

Comment: did u add `'connections' => [
    'neo4j' => [
        'driver' => 'neo4j',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'port'   => '7474',
        'username' => null,
        'password' => null
    ]
]`

Comment: Yeah, I added that configuration to my `database.php` file

Comment: Almost all code is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066341/laravel-form-data-not-saving-in-neo4j-graph-db)

Comment: I fixed it, thanks to the people who helped to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it: I decided to use `Vinelabs\NeoEloquent` package. Link is [here](https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent).
I added `neoeloquent` package requirement to `compser.json` file, ran `composer update` command. Then I added that package to `providers` array in `app/config/app.php`, then I replaced connection array in `app\config\database.php` like this:

```
'connections' => [
            'neo4j' => [
                    'driver' => 'neo4j',
                    'host'   => 'localhost',
                    'port'   => '7474',
                    'username' => null,
                    'password' => null
            ]
    ],
```

Then I wrote my own model file to push form data into neo4j db. And it worked.

Comment: i dont suppose you have this in any kind of repo to see it all together, do you? i'm facing a similar issue and can't fully visualize your structure here